# spring webapp project couldnt run after SVN checkout

Tags: spring, apache, tomcat, netbeans-7

I'm using Netbeans 7.2.1 on Linux Ubuntu 12.04, developing web application, using spring 3.1.0.RELEASE, spring 3.1.0. / hibernate, mavenized.
I used companies private SVN to access this project.
After opening the project, I used build with dependencies, then clean and build, then run project on apache-tomcat-7.0.41,
then the exception at the end of this post.

---

I tried the following:

1. un-deploying project from apache , then re-deploy
2. restarting tomcat
3. killing tomcat process
4. removed tomcat, then re-downloaded it and used another destination folder
5. removed netbeans cache
6. removed the project locally and reconnected to same svn and re-checked the svn.
7. deleted local maven repository ,re-downloaded jars,  same exception !
8. tried that on netbeans 7.3, same problem happened.

**notice**

- the same project "runs perfectly" on another machine !
- this problem happened when:

  - I got web app "X" from SVN "A" , I was developing web app "X" , running and everything is perfect .
  - I connected on same SVN "A" and got another web app "Y" , problem happened , and happened on another machine at work using the same steps.
  - webapp "y" runs perfectly on some machines at work ( used that SVN checkout too ).

I just want to  know what is this problem, where the problem lies.

---

```
Jun 12, 2013 11:10:30 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/ecommerce] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at viper.modules.ums.security.UserService.loadUserByUsername(UserService.java:32)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.TokenBasedRememberMeServices.processAutoLoginCookie(TokenBasedRememberMeServices.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.AbstractRememberMeServices.autoLogin(AbstractRememberMeServices.java:115)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:97)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:237)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(OpenSessionInViewFilter.java:198)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

---

Comment: Try clearing cookies in your browser too

Comment: Great added as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clearing your cookies in the browser. This may be affected if there have been changes to the remember me functions.

Comment: But why would an errant cookie cause a NPE? It suggests a bug somewhere.

Comment: We dont know what this method does: `processAutoLoginCookie`, perhaps it reads and parses the cookie, but after a change it is expecting a different structure to the cookie that he had stored on his machine.